# combinatoric proof $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k{n \choose k}^2=n{2n-1 \choose n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k{n \choose k}^2=n{2n-1 \choose n-1}$

my attempt:

(in the first note that :$n{2n-1 \choose n-1}=n{2n-1 \choose n}$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k{n \choose k}^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k{n \choose k}{n \choose n-k}=0{n \choose 0}{n \choose n-0}+1{n \choose 1}{n \choose n-1}+2{n \choose 2}{n \choose n-2}+......+(n-1){n \choose n-1}{n \choose 1}+n{n \choose n}{n \choose 0}$

let's assume that we have two set A and B that have n element for each,such that $A \cap B =\emptyset$

so $|A|=n$ and $|B|=n$

$0{n \choose 0}{n \choose n-0} $ it is the number of ways to choose 0 element from A and n element from B 0 time .

$1{n \choose 1}{n \choose n-1} $ it is the number of ways to choose 1 element from A and n-1 element from B 1 time .

$2{n \choose 2}{n \choose n-2} $ it is the number of ways to choose 2 element from A and n-2 element from B 2 time .

.

.

.

$n{n \choose n}{n \choose n-n} $ it is the number of ways to choose n element from A and 0 element from B n time .

so thier sum is the number of ways to choose n element from A and B  n time .

and we know that $|A+B|=|A+|B|=2n$

.
so it equal $n{2n \choose n} $

i know that's wrong but maybe my attempt can be devloped ...so now i search for my mistake

Comment: Well, what do you mean by " it is the number of ways to choose 2 element from A and n-2 element from B 2 time"? I'd think that would be $({n \choose 2}{n \choose n-2})^2$.

Comment: For a simpler example problem, if you want to choose a number from $1$ to $3$ and then another number from $1$ to $3$ there are $9$ ways to do this: First pick $1$, then pick $1$; or pick $1$, then pick $2$; etc. This corresponds to the 9 pairs $(1,1),(1,2)(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)$. There aren't $3*2 = 6$ ways.

Comment: Hint: You can think of $k {n \choose k}$ as the number of ways of choosing $k$ elements from $A$ and then "marking" one of the $k$ elements you've picked.

Comment: @jair-taylor thank you so much

Comment: Please, search, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5Enk%5Cbinom%7Bn%7Dk%5E2%3Dn%5Cbinom%7B2n-1%7D%7B2n%7D%24&p=1) to avoid asking a question that might have already been answered multiple times. (: Type in some part of your question, and there might be results on MSE and AoPS.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have $n$ women and $n$ men (*for a total of $2n$ people*) and we wish to make a committee with a female president out of these people of size $n$.

We can do this in a few different ways:

- First, pick the female president in $n$ possible ways.  Then, among the remaining $2n-1$ people, choose $n-1$ of them to serve as regular members on the committee.

$$n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$$

- Break apart into cases based on how many women end up on the committee, letting the number of women in each case be called $k$.  With $k$ women on the committee, choose which $k$ of the $n$ women they happen to be.  Then, choose which of those $k$ women were designated as being president.  Finally, of the $n$ men choose $k$ of the men to *not* be on the committee (*leaving the remaining $n-k$ men to serve on the committee*)

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}^2$$

As these expressions both are valid ways of counting the same scenario, they must be equal.  QED

Comment: thank you so much